# Testing Sentry with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, sentry

I am testing my error boundaries to React and noticed in Codecov that there is a particular part of my Sentry function that hasn't been tested.

[image]

I have tried to use jest.mock("@sentry/browser") and mocking Sentry, however, can't seem to get the lines tested. The Sentry import is mocking correctly but not `scope`.

Here is an example of my attempt at mocking.

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser"
const mock_scope = jest.fn(() => {
  return { setExtras: null }
})
Sentry.withScope = jest.fn().mockImplementation(mock_scope)
```

Comment: Since its a third party function, I would suggest using spyOn on Object `Sentry` and method `withScope`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The untested lines are this callback function being passed to `Sentry.withScope`:

```
scope => {
  scope.setExtras(errorInfo);
  Sentry.captureException(error);
}
```

Since `Sentry.withScope` has been mocked you can use [`mockFn.mock.calls`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls) to retrieve the callback function passed to it.

Once you have retrieved the callback function, you can call it directly to test it.

Here is a slightly simplified working example:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

jest.mock('@sentry/browser');  // <= auto-mock @sentry/browser

const componentDidCatch = (error, errorInfo) => {
  Sentry.withScope(scope => {
    scope.setExtras(errorInfo);
    Sentry.captureException(error);
  });
};

test('componentDidCatch', () => {
  componentDidCatch('the error', 'the error info');

  const callback = Sentry.withScope.mock.calls[0][0];  // <= get the callback passed to Sentry.withScope
  const scope = { setExtras: jest.fn() };
  callback(scope);  // <= call the callback

  expect(scope.setExtras).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the error info');  // Success!
  expect(Sentry.captureException).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the error');  // Success!
});
```

---

Note that this line:

```
const callback = Sentry.withScope.mock.calls[0][0];
```

...is getting the first argument of the first call to `Sentry.withScope`, which is the callback function.

Comment: Perfect - this worked like a charm. I had not used mock.calls before, this was the missing part of my knowledge to get this working.

Comment: You saved me with this answer. I spent a good amount of time scratching my head wondering how to test this exact situation. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This was really helpful for me as well!

Comment: I never thought about this reverse mock call, using  the mock.call and mock the parameters. Helped me a lot. Awesome!

Comment: i must be missing something! but `mock` does not exist on `withScope`.

Answer (score 5):

An addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301544/4612064). The solution there requires to manually invoke the callback (see the `callback(scope);  // <= call the callback` line in the test code).

Here is how to make it work automatically:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser'
jest.mock('@sentry/browser')

// Update the default mock implementation for `withScope` to invoke the callback
const SentryMockScope = { setExtras: jest.fn() }
Sentry.withScope.mockImplementation((callback) => {
  callback(SentryMockScope)
})
```

And then the test code becomes:

```
test('componentDidCatch', () => {
  componentDidCatch('the error', 'the error info');

  expect(SentryMockScope.setExtras).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the error info');
  expect(Sentry.captureException).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the error');
});
```